# Clicking "Submit" opens php file rather than running script

Tags: php, contact-form

**Syntax** If I change `<?=` to `<php echo` then the website no longer displays, I get a 500 error.

**Edit Again** None of the answers in the duplicate question solve the issue.

**Edit** I have updated the code, as below, to fix the syntax errors in error messages and change the file to index.php.

The problems persists. When I enter an invalid name or email, and click submit, it opens the PHP file, rather than displaying the error message in the span. When I enter valid details and click submit, it sends the email (so script is working) but still opens the PHP file rather than displaying success message in the div.

I have a contact form on my page as follows:

```
<form action="form_process.php" method="post" class="form" id="form1">

  <p class="name">
    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name" class= "feedback-input" value="<?= $name ?>"/>
    <span class="error"><?= $name_error ?></span>
  </p>

  <p class="email">
    <input name="email" type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" class= "feedback-input" value="<?= $email ?>"/>
    <span class="error"><?= $email_error ?></span>
  </p>

  <p class="text">
    <textarea name="message" type="text" id="comment" placeholder="Message" class= "feedback-input" value="<?= $message ?>"></textarea>
  </p>

  <div class="submit">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button-blue"/>
    <div class="ease"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="success"><?= $success; ?></div>
</form>
```

This is the php file:

```
    <?php 

// define variables and set to empty values
$name_error = $email_error = "";
$name = $email = $message = $success = "";

//form is submitted with POST method
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $name_error = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $name_error = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $email_error = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $email_error = "Invalid email format"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $message = "";
  } else {
    $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
  }

  if ($name_error == '' and $email_error == '' ){
      $message_body = '';
      unset($_POST['submit']);
      foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
          $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
      }

      $to = 'xxx@xxx.com';
      $subject = 'Contact Form Submit';
      if (mail($to, $subject, $message)){
          $success = "Message sent, thank you for contacting us!";
          $name = $email = $message = '';
      }
  }

}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
```

When I click submit on my computer (mac) it opens the php file and displays the code.

When i click it on the actual website (hosted on dreamhost with php installed) it opens the file and displays a blank page.

I've taken a look at some of thew other issues on here and it doesn't seem to be related to them. Really not sure what's wrong? Would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: If you go to a link that is not on a web server, then your content will not be executed. It needs the web server to be executing the PHP. I don't see any page output from the PHP, so I would expect to see nothing as the result.

Comment: The php file is on the web server. I meant I had tested it locally, by opening index.html in browser, as well as uploading to the web server.

Comment: What do you expect to be displayed?

Comment: Change to index.php and change your closing php tags to `?>` rather than `>?`

Comment: @LiamG done, the error is still there.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts An error message, in the span, when there is an error, or a success message, in the div, when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

By the code you have provided in your question the only issue i see that could make this happen is that you have typos at the php syntax. For example: `<span class="error"><?= $email_error >?</span>`, where it should be like this: `<span class="error"><?php echo $email_error ?></span>`.

Comment: His syntax is shorthand PHP, it's fine if it is turned on in configuration

Comment: Didn't see the `>?` where it should be `?>`

Answer (score -1):

I am quoting your comment:

> The php file is on the web server. I meant I had tested it locally, by opening index.html in browser, as well as uploading to the web server.

You cannot write PHP code on .html files - change the extension to .php to the index file.

Comment: This is not entirely true. You can have any extension you want run any type of code. URL rewrites are very popular in this modern web dev age.

Comment: He didn't mention the fact that he is using URL rewrites. If he does that I agree with you

Comment: @YlberVeliu I've done this and the result is the same.